# Precise String.Split

Tags: c#, sql, syntax

I have a file that contains SQL statements that is delimited by semicolons, is there a way to make sure that strings in my file that have semicolons inside values to be inserted won't be affected by String.Split?

Example:

```
Insert Into items(Description) Values('Anti Surge T; LBC Slow Blow 6.3 x 32mm 7A / 250V');
Insert Into items(Description) Values('SSA 215');
```

I want to the whole `'Anti Surge T; LBC Slow Blow 6.3 x 32mm 7A / 250V'` value to be inserted into my table row. But since I using `<sql_statemet>.Split(new char { ';' })` the sql statement is not complete since there's a semicolon inside `Anti Surge T; LBC...`

> Edit: Everybody has the same
>   sentiments. Thanks guys, it worked. I
>   think I should just make a better
>   delimiter for this too. XD

Comment: `.Split` will tear every single semicolon that it finds.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand - you want to String.Split but prevent semi colons being split?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think so something like that is available

but you can try "`RegularExpression`" not sure but may resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`Regex.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx) where you can define a pattern to split.

Update: You can start with Regex: `"([^;]*?('.*?')?)*?;\\s*"`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to split depending on more than just a single character / string you should use

```
Regex.Split
```

there you can define the valid expression very precise